# Atom - spell-check package not working with language-markdown package

Tags: packages, spell-check, markdown, atom-editor

I recently installed an additional markdown package ([language-markdown](https://github.com/burodepeper/language-markdown)), and now Atom's default [spell-check](https://atom.io/packages/spell-check) package no longer works on markdown files even though the list of Grammars scope in spell-check includes markdown:

```
# List of scopes for languages which will be checked for misspellings
source.asciidoc, source.gfm, text.git-commit, text.plain, text.plain.null-grammar, text.markdown, source.md,
```

Markdown spell-check was working fine before language-markdown installation.

Is something wrong with my scope or settings?

Answer (score 2):

Add `text.md` to the list of spell-check scope. (`Packages > Spell Check > Settings > Grammars`)

---

Since spell-check was working fine before, I will assume you got no [dictionary misconfigurations](https://github.com/atom/spell-check#changing-the-dictionary).

The main issue is language-markdown scope is different than the standard [language-gfm](https://atom.io/packages/language-gfm); Atom's default markdown package. You can log the scope and see that for yourself:

[image: Editor scope Command]

Which will give you the following if logged within language-markdown scope:

> Scopes at Cursor
>
> - text.md

So add `text.md` to the list of spell-check Grammars scope.